# Update database not affect for different cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem, I want to create a condition for different cases, for example:

> when (WeekDay == 2) the field CanWork2 should be 1 but this not happen
> just change 1 field "CanWork1"

```
UPDATE
    Emps
SET
    CanWork1 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 1 THEN 1 ELSE CanWork1 END,
    CanWork2 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 2 THEN 1 ELSE CanWork2 END,
    CanWork3 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 3 THEN 1 ELSE CanWork3 END,
    CanWork4 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 4 THEN 1 ELSE CanWork4 END,
    CanWork5 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 5 THEN 1 ELSE CanWork5 END,
    CanWork6 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 6 THEN 1 ELSE CanWork6 END,
    CanWork7 = CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 7 THEN 1 ELSE CanWork7 END
FROM
    #PS_EMPLOYEES AS Emps
    CROSS JOIN _PS_checkdays1 AS cd
```

[image]

Comment: @DaleK when the "WeekDay" field is equals 2, the "CanWork2" field should be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate before joining:

```
UPDATE Emps
    SET CanWork1 = COALESCE(cd.CanWork1, Emps.CanWork1),
        CanWork2 = COALESCE(cd.CanWork2, Emps.CanWork2),
        . . .
    FROM #PS_EMPLOYEES Emps CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 1 THEN 1 END) as CanWork1,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN cd.WeekDay = 2 THEN 1 END) as CanWork2,
                 . . . 
          FROM _PS_checkdays1 cd
         )  cd;
```

The `UPDATE` statement only updates each matching row once.  If the `JOIN` generates multiple rows, an arbitrary row is chosen for the update.